# Языковой суффикс /by и суффикс расширения .html на главной

Tags: .htaccess

Что делать чтобы url вида `http://zrobym.by/by` (белорусская версия - Falang) не преобразовывался в `http://zrobym.by/by.html` (иначе 404), расширение задано в .htaccess и убрать с сайта нельзя - обязательное условие.

Редиректы и склейки не помогают, видимо, правило про добавление .html - сильнее.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*/[^/.]+)($|\?)
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

(Joomla 2.7)

Comment: Но! появилась след. проблема: при переходе на русский язык (по нажатию на главной) происходит переадресация на такой адрес: http://zrobym.by/ru.html. хотя сайт доступен по http://zrobym.by, а в плагине указано, - не показывать суффикс языка по умолчанию.

Comment: Ой, стормозил: можно же так же добавить Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/ru) и Супер!!!! Спасибо , все работает!

Comment: перенёс и дополнил комментарий в ответ. если решение подходит, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ «принятым».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте перед первой строкой `rewriterule` добавить строку

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/by)
```

а чтобы игнорировались и `/by` и `/ru` можно указать такое условие:

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/(by|ru))
```